# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - October 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the first edition of the Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for October 2017

This report includes the following awards:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      320
2   grgarside                  290
3   oa-                        180
4   bmike, Monomeeth, fsb      130
5   Mark, dwightk               90
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 650.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/46/month/apple/2017-10-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   oa-                      250
2   grgarside                132
3   Allan                     77
4   klanomath                 69
5   bmike                     66
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   LangLangC                 689
2   Monomeeth                 389
3   bmike                     227
4   grgarside                 218
5   JW8                       178
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     69
2   Mark                      55
3   fsb                       51
4   oa-                       40
5   Scot                      37
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   oa-                      155
2   grgarside                129
3   JMY1000                  110
4   Monomeeth                108
5   Scot                      91
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    172
2   grgarside                 47
3   JMY1000                   26
4   Scot, IconDaemon          19
5   fsb, Mark                 15
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   fsb                       32
2   Scot                      29
3   Allan                     26
4   IconDaemon                22
5   grgarside                 20
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    12
2   oa-, Mark                 8
3   Tetsujin                  7
4   fsb                       6
5   patrix                    4
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   techraf                  53
2   grgarside                36
3   Allan                    35
4   fsb                      23
5   oa-                      15
```

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Has the WiFi KRACK vulnerability been patched for iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302360/has-the-wifi-krack-vulnerability-been-patched-for-ios)

   - Posted by: dwightk
   - Votes: **36**
2. [Why do we install software via `.dmg` files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301898/why-do-we-install-software-via-dmg-files)

   - Posted by: Remi.b
   - Votes: **25**
3. [What does it mean for consumers that Apple has released MacOS kernel as open source?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303132/what-does-it-mean-for-consumers-that-apple-has-released-macos-kernel-as-open-sou)

   - Posted by: DrWongKC
   - Votes: **17**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [What does it mean for consumers that Apple has released MacOS kernel as open source?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303132/what-does-it-mean-for-consumers-that-apple-has-released-macos-kernel-as-open-sou/303136#303136)

   - Answered by: Mike Scott
   - Votes: **34**
2. [What does it mean for consumers that Apple has released MacOS kernel as open source?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303132/what-does-it-mean-for-consumers-that-apple-has-released-macos-kernel-as-open-sou/303196#303196)

   - Answered by: Adam Davis
   - Votes: **33**
3. [Why do we install software via `.dmg` files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301898/why-do-we-install-software-via-dmg-files/301900#301900)

   - Answered by: Sirens
   - Votes: **32**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What does it mean for consumers that Apple has released MacOS kernel as open source?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303132/what-does-it-mean-for-consumers-that-apple-has-released-macos-kernel-as-open-sou)

   - Posted by: DrWongKC
   - Views: **8,436**
2. [Has the WiFi KRACK vulnerability been patched for iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302360/has-the-wifi-krack-vulnerability-been-patched-for-ios)

   - Posted by: dwightk
   - Views: **7,486**
3. [Why do we install software via `.dmg` files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301898/why-do-we-install-software-via-dmg-files)

   - Posted by: Remi.b
   - Views: **3,685**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [oa-](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/201668/oa)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [LangLangC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/251859/langlangc)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [oa-](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/201668/oa)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [fsb](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/88313/fsb)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Techraf](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/145449/techraf)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [dwightk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/70930/dwightk)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Mike Scott](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2201/mike-scott)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [DrWongKC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/228954/drwongkc)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In October our [Moderators](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 572 flags with an average handling time of 12 minutes. In summary, we:

- deleted 213 comments
- deleted 357 posts
- closed 164 posts
- edited 274 posts
- created 192 posts
- created 502 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users!

Keep up the great work! :)

Comment: This is cool. Thanks for doing it!